# Given a field, $K$, are there two DVRs $A,B$ for the same field $K$, such that $A\cap B$ is also a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Clearly, we cannot construct any such DVR's when $K=\mathbb{Q}$, or when $K=\mathbb{F}_q$, so we must look to more intricate examples. Is it possible to construct such DVR's when $\mathrm{char\,} K = 0$? My intuition tells me that we should consider positive characteristic, but I can't figure out how to construct anything like this.

Comment: $char \mathbb Q=0$.

Comment: What is a D.V.R?

Comment: But $\mathbb{Q}$ is far from the only field with characteristic $0$. What's your point?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring (there are many equivalent definitions)

Comment: You are asking if this can be done in characteristic zero, which typically means if this is always doable in characteristic zero. If you are asking for  an example, you should start your question by "does there exists a $K$ such that..."

Comment: I realized that the title was a little confusing, so I corrected it.

Comment: The answer is no. If you pick two DVRs with the same field of quotients, then their intersection is a ring with exactly two maximal ideals: in particular it can never be a field.

Comment: See Theorem 12.2 of [Matsumura , Commutative Ring Theory](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/cmi/References/Matsumura_Commutative_Theory.pdf) for a proof of the fact I said in the above comment.